# No unique bean of type exception. Issues with autowiring inherited classes

Tags: java, exception, autowired

I am new to Java code and I had an exception about the autowiring a service interface.

I have to classes A and B. B extends from A and each class has its own services.

```
@Service
@Qualifier("aService")
public interface AService {
    //Some methods
}

@Service
@Qualifier("bService")
public interface BService {
    //Some methods
}
```

I am using these interfaces in some classes, and I have put the annotation `@Qualifer`.

```
public class Test() {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("aService")
private AService aService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bService")
private BService bService;

    //Some code
}
```

But I keep getting the exception :

```
No unique bean of type [com.analysis.dw.AService] is defined : Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface com.analysis.dw.AService]: expected at least 1 matching bean
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you any class in your classpath that **implements** `aService`?

Comment: Yes I have one class that implements AService and another one that implements BService.

Comment: It says: expected **at least 1** matching bean

Answer (score 2):

Use annotations on class, not an interface!

```
@Service
@Qualifier("aService")
public class AServiceImpl implements AService {
    //Some methods
}
```

Spring will not instantiate interface.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
@Qualifier
```

annotation from AService and BService interfaces.

Look which beans implements the interface AService.

Between beans which implements the interface AService, choose the bean you want to inject on class Test, in the field

```
private AService aService;
```

In the AService implementation bean you have choosen, use the

```
@Service("aService")
```

annotation.

Mantein annotations on your Test class,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("aService")
private AService aService;
```

The same scenario for BService if would exist more than one implementation for the BService interface.

Answer (score 0):

a) see Grzegoz' answer
b) this is not the way to do it:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("aService")
```

Instead, This is the way to do it:

```
@Service("aService")
```

`@Qualifier` is for injecting a service, not for constructing it